# Adding Hardware Letterboxing?

Tags: resolution

I've got a Nintendo Switch that can only output in 1080p, and I was trying to hook it up to my desk monitor (Dell U2415) which is a 16:10 1920x1200p monitor. Naturally when the Switch outputs at 1080p, my Dell Monitor just stretches the image, and there's no option in the Dell Monitor Menu to enable a 16:9 mode that would just add letterboxing. There are no scaling or stretching settings on the Switch that would help either.

I was wondering if there was a device that could add letterboxing to the video output of the Switch (so just taking the 16:9 feed and padding black pixels to the top and bottom so it fills a 16:10 aspect ratio) so that I could avoid stretching on my monitor.

Or is there any other idea that someone might have that could help in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: A box that could do this would be so niche that it would cost more than buying a new monitor that doesn't suck.